# Play/pause audio stream NodeJs

Tags: node.js, audio, stream, lame, speaker

I'm using NodeJs with lame and speaker to play a mp3 sound like this :

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/dir/file.mp3');
var decoder = new lame.Decoder();
var speaker;

stream.pipe(decoder).on('format', function(format) {
    speaker = new Speaker(format);
    this.pipe(speaker);
});
```

This code works fine, my problem is when I want it to pause :

```
stream.unpipe();
```

It works, the sound pauses but after 3-4 seconds, I want it to pause instantly. I've seen this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225379/node-lame-play-stop-and-resume-audio but there's no answer.
I think there is a delay caus the stream already buffered the next 3-4 secs when I call unpipe (or am I wrong ?) and if so, is there a way to manage properly the buffer, or to clean it when I call unpipe ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [.pause()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) method, in concoction with [.resume()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) because right now you are detaching your stream, and closing the file.

Why dose it takes few seconds to stop playing? Because the stream has still data in its buffer. On average that will be around 70KB of data, since streams read data in chunks.